# OpenSuSE: Color calibaration stops working after upgrade 15.3 → 15.4. How to re-calibrate?

Tags: opensuse, color-management

After upgrading my OpenSuSE 15.3 machine to 15.4, my monitor displays colors completely differently than before the upgrade. Apparently, the color calibration I had performed by using Argyll, DisplayCAL, and a Datacolor Spyder X has disappeared. Recalibrating failed because of a bunch of issues:

1. OpenSuSE 15.4 no longer supports DisplayCAL. Obviously it's no longer maintained.
2. Color management does exist in the KDE Control Center (under Hardware → Color correction), but doesn't work either. Instead of a color management module, only an error message is displayed: "you need Gnome color management installed in order to calibrate devices".  But: I've already got `gnome-color-manager` installed!
3. I've found out that a particular program from Gnome's color manager is required: `gcm-calibrate`. But: The official `gnome-color-manager` package from OpenSuSE lacks this piece of software. Why?

About problem #2 there has been a bug filed at KDE, but without a solution or even a workaround: [Bug #433068](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433068)

Here's some system information:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  rpm -q gnome-color-manager 
gnome-color-manager-3.36.0-150400.2.10.x86_64
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  rpm -q argyllcms     
argyllcms-2.2.0-150400.1.10.x86_64
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  uname -a
Linux epica 5.14.21-150400.24.60-default #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Apr 12 12:13:32 UTC 2023 (93dbe2e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need a well-calibrated monitor as I do a lot of photo editing, so using an uncalibrated monitor is not an option for me. So: Is there an alternative method or color manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving this issue took me quite a lot of patience, but one after the other:

1. OpenSuSE 15.4 no longer came with DisplayCAL. Neither does 15.5. Reason: DisplayCAL used to work with the age-old Python 2.7. There is now a [fork named `displaycal-py3`](https://github.com/eoyilmaz/displaycal-py3), which requires Python 3.8 or newer. Standard for OpenSuSE 15.4 and 15.5, sadly, is still the fairly outdated 3.6.
2. There is a semi-official Python 3.11 RPM package named `python311` for OpenSuSE 15.5, so I installed it. **But:** DisplayCAL had to be installed from PyPi and required `wxPython`, which did not come with `python311`. Setting it up from PyPi is a very tedious and time-consuming task, as the build script is extremely buggy and requires an [ugly hack](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2422) to work around it.
3. Once DisplayCAL worked again, it took the well-known 30-minute procedure and a colorimeter to recalibrate the monitor.